# Calculate null and not null count for 3 columns in an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 columns in a table:

```
v_type1|v_type2|v_type3
```

These columns can contain NULLs. What I need is to calculate the number of NULL and NOT NULL values for each of the 3 columns. The result must be one row (and actually there would 6 columns):

```
v_type1_null_counts|v_type1_notnull_counts|v_type2_null_counts|v_type2_notnull_counts|v_type3_null_counts|v_type3_notnull_counts
```

I tried with joining but did not finish with a result.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select c1 as v_type1_notnull_cnt,  
       total - c1 as v_type1_null_cnt,
       c2 as v_type2_notnull_cnt,
       total - c2 as v_type2_null_cnt,
       c3 as v_type3_notnull_cnt ,
       total - c3 as v_type3_null_cnt
from (
   select  count(*) as  total, 
           count(v_type1) as c1,
           count(v_type2) as c2,
           count(v_type3) as c3
   FROM your_table
) t
```

Answer (score 2):

`count()` counts non-NULL values.  So the easiest way is:

```
select count(v_type1) as v_type1_not_null,
       count(v_type2) as v_type2_not_null,
       count(v_type3) as v_type3_not_null,
       (count(*) - count(v_type1)) as v_type1_null,
       (count(*) - count(v_type2)) as v_type2_null,
       (count(*) - count(v_type3)) as v_type3_null
from t;
```